# Migrations Error in MVC 5 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Im develop the  MVC project, i have a some issue for this , im already to created database , but i cant update DB  in add `PM> Update-Database`  method,
displayed the following error , how can i fix it?

**No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'MVCMovei'. (In Visual Studio you can use the Enable-Migrations command from Package Manager Console to add a migrations configuration).**

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the package manager console run the following command

- Enable-Migrations

After that run Command

- Add-Migrations "AnyName" (initialmigration etc)

After that Run

- Update-Database (if you want to make changes in database)

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue whilst working on MVC Movie App tutorial too. Using MS Visual Studio Nuget Packet Manager(PM) do the following;

```
PM> Enable-Migrations
Checking if the context targets an existing database...
Code First Migrations enabled for project MVC Movie.

PM> Add-Migration Initial
Scaffolding migration 'Initial'.

PM> Update-Database
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Applying explicit migrations: [201808240707259_Initial].
Applying explicit migration: 201808240707259_Initial.
Running Seed method.
```

To follow these solution in detail use these [resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-3) from MS Docs. I hope this help other starters on SO who get stuck.